# Django: Reducing number of queries when filtering by foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following code:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)

    def get_books_for_same_author(self):
        return Book.objects.filter(author = self.author)
```

When calling `get_books_for_same_author`, my common sense tells me that 2 DB queries are issued - one to get `self.author` and another for getting the books for this author.

Am I right? If so, is there a way to get the same results with only one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that would involve two queries, if you have not already fetched `self.author` for that instance either by accessing it directly, or by using `select_related` when you originally fetched the book.

However you don't actually need the author object at all here: the book model directly contains an underlying `author_id` field which you can use instead:

```
return Book.objects.filter(author=self.author_id)
```

and this will only incur one query.